# is it possible to get the unique User ID to prevent MFA in angular?

Tags: angular, device, fingerprinting

i want to get the unique User ID to prevent the Multi factor auth for the same user.
is it possible to achieve this? or there is any open source js lib with higher accuracy?

i try fingerprintjs-pro but it's piad and also try client.js
it's accuracy is not to much higher

Comment: Please share code sample

Comment: Don't you have a database/backend to store it?

Comment: but first thing is to get the unique ID
then i will be able to store in DB